# Make Microsoft Security Essentials ignore items in shadow copy

Tags: backup, ms-security-essentials, vss

On my computer are some programs that I have written and compiled, but MSE kept finding them and was always wanting to quarantine them, so I added my dev directory to the ignore list.  That's fine.

But I run backups at night which use Volume Shadow Copy, and MSE finds my little programs in the shadow copy!  I've tried several times to create an exclusion rule, but I haven't hit on the right solution yet.  So every time a backup runs, I have to confirm the files to be "allowed".

The items are listed like this:

```
file:\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy22\dev\myprogram\myprogram.exe
```

The number always changes in the path, so I had created a filter like this in MSE's Settings under "Excluded files and locations":

```
file:\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy*\dev\*
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Seems like the simplest solution would be to submit a sample to Microsoft so your application stops being flagged altogether.

Comment: Never thought of doing that.  I always disable any kind of communication in programs of that nature.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't have any effect.